# Problem with starting nodejs server in production

Tags: javascript, node.js, typescript, tsc, ts-node

Well, currently I have a problem with starting the typescript app after it was transpiled to js.

My tsconfig:

```json
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "module": "NodeNext",
    "moduleResolution": "NodeNext",
    "baseUrl": "src",
    "target": "ESNext",
    "outDir": "build",
    "strict": true,
    "removeComments": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "noImplicitAny": false,
    "esModuleInterop": true
  },
  "include": ["src/**/*.ts"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", ".idea"],
  "ts-node": {
    "require": ["tsconfig-paths/register"]
  }
}
```

I start the dev server with: `ts-node src/index.ts`.
But when I try to compile ts to js and run it with `tsc && node build/index.js` command, the following error occur `Error: Cannot find module 'some-module-with-absolute-path'`.

Google told me that the cause might be the absolute paths and tsc can't convert them. So I tried `tsc && ts-node build/index.js` and it worked!

Does using ts-node like this in production have any downsides (perfomance or whatever) and how do I run prod build in a proper way? Thanks.

Comment: Is there any reason, why you are using absolute paths?

Comment: @MauriceNino ah, no reason. I'm just used to them in react/angular. So if there's no solution, then I'll change them all :(

Comment: "I'm just used to them in react/angular" I have used React professionally for the better part of a decade, and I've at least played with Angular, and I never once (IIRC) have used an absolute path for an import/require. I think not doing that is basically your answer, because I'm guessing something that used to be in `src` is now in `lib` or whatever your build directory is.

Comment: What's an "absolute path"? `C:/blah/file.js`?

Answer (score 0):

Personally I don't *think* there's anything wrong with running ts-node in prod. However I would say there's something messy about absolute paths. I would kill that habit asap, as working with others will instantly break all your imports. You might install your project at `/User/Documents/TheProject` while someone else installs at `/User/Projects/TheProject`. And now all of the imports have to change. This is why 10 times out of 10 if you're importing anything that you didn't npm install you should use a relative import. Basically pretend you don't know where the project is on the system. You can only rely on the root of the project and the hierarchy you develop in it.